# Possible to do insert into select in jpa using mysql?

Tags: mysql, jpa

I am trying to make a simple backup of data into a history table at the end of each day.

But it seems to fail to execute as it should. It will not generate an error. But it will also not do the insert as exepected. It will run clean through using Mysql workbench.

```
query = em.createNativeQuery("insert into sgdatatest.ASSETHISTORY select * from sgdatatest.ASSET where dayssinceepoch <= :dayssinceepoch");
        query.setParameter("daysSinceEpoch", daysSinceEpoch);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I think JPA doesn't support named parameters in native queries. Does it work if you use positional parameter: `where dayssinceepoch <= ?1` and `query.setParameter(1, daysSinceEpoch);`? Strange you don't get an exception, though.

Comment: Changed to just concat the statements. Seems to work :)

Comment: Can you try with positional parameter, just to check if that was the issue with your original attempt?

Comment: JPA has nothing to do with it, since its "native query" handling is simply what JDBC allows.

Comment: @NeilStockton I was refering to JPA specification, section 3.10.16.4, where it says `The use of named parameters is not defined for native SQL queries. Only positional parameter binding
for SQL queries may be used by portable applications.`

Comment: This works query = em.createNativeQuery("insert ignore into sgdatatest.QUOTEHISTORY select * from sgdatatest.QUOTE where dayssinceepoch <= ?1");
  query.setParameter(1, daysSinceEpoch);
  query.executeUpdate();